# Взаимодействие php

Tags: php

Как сделать взаимодействие игроков на php? Как арена, например, во всех играх есть браузерных.

Comment: @chops, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!
Я не могу уловить логику, допустим, есть кнопка "Подать заявку на бой", появляется игрок на странице, который подал ее, и есть возможность вступить с ним в бой - это окей.  
Понятно, что для каждого боя надо создать запись в таблице battle с полями id_battle, id_user-1, id_user2 и т.д.

Comment: Но как начать этот бой?Генерировать какую-то уникальную ссылку? И как определить, что эту ссылку могут использовать только эти игроки. Есть мысль на время боя какие-то куки генерировать одинаковые для этих игроков и добавлять эти же значение в таблицу текущего боя. Плюс не очень понятно, как  отобразить действия одного пользователя на экране другого, каждую секунду обновлять данные из БД через AJAX?

Comment: Бой - это или страница, на которую переходят оба игрока (можно и автоматически), или если столкнулись на поле - событие при пересечении координат объектов.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ еще раз! Логика начинает вырисовываться в голове. Я не так давно изучаю php, в данном примере идет речь о игре "Морской бой" многопользовательский, возможно стоит попробовать взаимодействие пользователей на чем-нибудь более простом?

Comment: вначале сделайте обычный морской бой 10х10  между двумя пользователями

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробую понять Вас: браузерная игра  предполагает хранение информаци о игроках, некой карты, и, предположим, взаимодействии игроков  между собой, с статичными персонажами и, возможно, другими объектами виртуального мира - для этого используются бызы данных, максимум распространения получила СУБД MySQL, но она не панацея.

В современном подходе к веб-разработке применима технология Ajax - она позволит без перезагрузки страницы общаться  с сервером.

Это было вступление, которое подготавливало к самому ответу.

Итак, предположим: виртуальный бой двух игроков: создаётся запись в таблицу боёв с начальным состоянием игроков, начинается бой, удары по противнику, применение магии... - делается запись в таблицу "изменение состояние игрока во время боя" -  туда записываем все нужные нам параметры состояния игрока во время определенного боя (ищем, как ключами связывать таблицы), по окончанию боя записываем результаты в таблицу боёв и обновляем таблицу "текущее состояние воина" (предположим, что их у игрока больше одного - тогда заводим отдельную таблицу и ключами связываем их между собой)...

Роль PHP - приём  POST запросов от клиента, их обработка на сервере, обновление данных  БД, предоставление нужного контента от текущей ситуации в игре, поддержка функциональности сайта, учет внутренней валюты, взаимодействие по API с платежными системами...

P.S. В вопросе явно указано Php, но любой серверный язык программирования с этим справится, следите за нагрузкой.

UPD: во время всего пользования сайтом храните в сессиях id игроков, так вы избежите доступ к боям другими игрокам. Разберитесь с событиями в js - клик мыши, нажатие клавиши...
После каждого события во время боя у одного  игрока отправляйте информацию о нём, делайте запись, если что-то поменялось (вдруг - промах), и обновляйте другому  раз в секунду, к примеру (потому как второй игрок может поменять свои параметры), для того чтобы это было незаметно, делайте длительную анимацию на 2-3 секунды (пока сервер обновляет информацию на экране монитора).